Как решить проблему в PyCharm?
Я новичок помогите
Во время компилирования "Py" файла в "EXE" происходит ошибка
"PS D:\PyGame> pyinstaller main.py
pyinstaller : Имя "pyinstaller" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

pyinstaller main.py



CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

работаю в PyCharm с модулем "pyinstaller"
